# Why have many programmers moved to using exception handling for input or output?

Tags: exception-handling, io

Why have many programmers moved to using exception handling for input or output? For these programmers, what is the motivation behind this decision?

Comment: The abundance of C programmers and projects in C disagree with your claims of "almost all"

Comment: Java programmers don't get a choice!

Comment: "almost all programmers, in almost all cases" - are you begging for downvotes?

Comment: I/O function is a non-pure function. So, Runtime exception handling must be taken care. But am not sure, on what basis, one would ask: "why have almost all programmers...?"

Comment: Survival of the fittest.  Exceptions work better than the alternative.

Comment: Why do you thing that "almost all programmers" have moved to using exception handling for I/O?

Comment: This question would be significantly better with an example or links to some external source supporting your premise.  As-is, it just looks like asking why most programmers don't write in assembly any more.

Comment: Damon, welcome to Stack Exchange! Robert Harvey and I have edited your question to be more user friendly (it doesn't add any information to the question to tell us that you're a beginner) and to be less opinion based. Stack Exchange is about experts answering answerable questions, and a question that is simply asking for opinions won't receive a lot of support on SO. See [help] and [ask].

Answer (score 18):

### Because input and output are unreliable.

Exceptions are, in part, an acknowledgement that there are going to be conditions which the software cannot reasonably recover from.

1. Premature end-of-line termination, syntax error or any number of validation error conditions,
2. Inputs are too long or large to reasonably accomodate,
3. Keyboard gets unplugged,
4. Hard disk runs out of space, etc.

Exceptions are the programmer's way of saying "I can't continue under the present conditions."  In essence, when you throw an exception, you're giving up and asking for a do-over.

You can do this without gracefully exiting your input/output subroutine or even worrying about memory management, because the orderly disposal of the relevant objects is already built into the exception-handling mechanism.

You can control where in your code the exception gets handled without elaborate `if` structures, intricate state mechanisms or call tree tracking.

Comment: *"Because input and output are unreliable"* does not explain why exceptions are used instead of error-codes. As such, I believe I have a better explanation (despite the -15 downvotes) at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/279911/24257 .

Answer (score 10):

### Because exceptions (as opposed to error code return values) cannot be ignored.

The typical code for i/o calls before exceptions, was usually written in terms of printf/scanf/gets/puts.

These functions return values that allow the developer to check for errors, but that is not trivial.

Most developers, knowing the error handling is not trivial, simply ommit it; They tend to think a typical fscanf call should look like this:

```
int a;
FILE *f = /* ... */;
fscanf(f, "%d", &a);
```

when it should probably look like this:

```
switch(fscanf(f, "%d", &a))
{
case EOF:
    // todo: handle EOF case
    break;
case 0:
    puts("could not read 'a'");
    break;
case 1:
    // handle success case
    break;
}
```

This code can (to a point) be extracted into a function, parametrized and (probably) hidden inside a wrapper on scanf, or a macro (both of which have downsides).

If you do not write it though, your application simply doesn't handle the errors. On the other hand, exceptions give you more useful error information, propagate naturally up the call stack and cannot be ignored (if you do, they *will* stop your application).

Comment: Not to mention that interfaces of some methods are just incredibly obfuscated. Some function might return -1 to indicate an error, some might return 0. Some functions will set output parameters even when it fails, some don't. Exceptions are just one more step in making it easier to write increasingly safe code, without having to rely on the programmer understand *all* the intricacies of what they're trying to do. Languages like Java or C# exploit this a lot to make it much easier to write correct and safe code. They do require other infrastructure to work well, though - GC, defined runtime...

Comment: @utnapistim, This is an unbalanced comparison. If you wish to weigh the use case whereby we have multiple error codes, you must weigh it against  the equivalent use case whereby we have multiple exception paths, as can be seen in the long snippet in http://stackoverflow.com/a/315967/632951 . If you are going to weigh the "catch-all"  — `} catch(e) { /* handle all */ }` , then you must weigh it against the two-state errorcode `0` and `1` which doesn't use `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

## Because it is more readable code.

For example (i love examples):

```
function myFunc(someInput:String) : OutputType
  if firstErrorCondition(someInput)
    throw new FirstConditionException
  if secondErrorCondition(someInput)
    throw new SecondConditionException
  if thirdErrorCondition(someInput)
    throw new ThirdConditionException
  // do some other fancy stuff and return value eventually
```

What if here we will return a value instead of throwing exceptions? Let me see:

```
function myFunc(someInput:String) : OutputType
  if firstErrorCondition(someInput)
    return -1
  if secondErrorCondition(someInput)
    return -2
  if thirdErrorCondition(someInput)
    return -3
  // do some other fancy stuff and return value eventually
```

Okay, it is still fine. But how clients code will looks?

```
OutputType result = myFunc(someInput)
```

That's a common part of it. Exceptions:

```
try {
  OutputType result = myFunc(someInput)
  //other operations
} catch (FirstErrorCondition e) {
  //do some exception handling
} catch (SecondErrorCondition e) {
  //do some magic
} catch (ThirdErrorCondition e) {
  //or just inform user that is a problem
} finally {
  //close everything and clean up after some doing
}
```

As a regular developer i can see what code is responsible for each part of error/exception.

```
OutputType result = myFunc(someInput)
switch(result) {
  case -1:
    //meh meh
  case -2:
    //meh meh
  case -3:
    //meh meh
  default:
    //and here we have a REGULAR code
}
```

Other plus of exceptions: It can be ommited in client code but it *will throw exception eventually when issue occured*. It will not be silient, buggy and unreadeable code.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with remaining answer on one fact : That "exceptional return" does happen and needs to be handled.

But reason why exceptions exist is not that exceptional returns exist. It is possible to have "return values" for each of the possible error states, just like C does. The reason why exceptions are preferable to C-like error handling is that it is extremely rare that error from a function will be handled in immediate caller. It is much more common for error state to bubble up the stack until it gets into place where it can be reasonably handled. Also, single "handling" code will handle different method calls.

If you are using C-like error handling, you have to create extensive amount of code to do the bubbling and aggregation of errors all the way to the handler code. This requires discipline and rigor and drastically complicates return values from methods, where every possible exceptional return needs to have it's own value). Exceptions and infrastructure around them simply do all of this for you. And while I do agree exception handling too needs some level of discipline and rigor, it needs it much less.

Answer (score 0):

Remember first you are solving problems.  Imagine a simple solution, adding two numbers.  You should do the following.

1. Code the successful path in a test first.  Ie. given 2, 2 return 4, given 1,2 return 3 and so on.
2. Write the code to pass the test.
3. Figure out ways to break things. Ie  Given 1 raise exception Not enough args, Given A, 3 raise exception incorrect arg type.

That is the approach I always take.  Its very TDD but it works for me and I have to say I find it quicker than any other approach.  Exceptions are clean.  And in a language like python there would be no coding required to raise most of them.. 'a'+2 raises an exception for free :-)

Answer (score -1):

I find exceptions are cleaner for code style since I can wrap the code and deal with any errors in a specific location (the catch block), as opposed to littering my code with lots of if statements (`if (result == -1)`), to check for error conditions.

Answer (score -4):

### [Behavioral Economics #101: because it's the easier way.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_choice_theory#Actions.2C_assumptions.2C_and_individual_preferences)

Exceptions are, in part, an acknowledgement that error-handling is [**hard**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/253393/632951) and while we can recover from exceptions, it's [much easier not to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4393197/632951).

Exceptions are the programmer's way of saying "I have this ideal situation that must be matched and I'll not bother [spending more lines](http://plasmasturm.org/log/linesspent/) nor time handling situations that are not ."  In essence, when you do a "catch-all" type of exception handling, you're [**giving up**](https://www.lighterra.com/papers/exceptionsharmful/):

```
} catch(e) {
    print("Don't even know what error it is but **there's an error**. Exit / Retry.");
}
```

(Besides "catch-all" exceptions, there's also the "one-by-one" [longform style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/315967/632951) which is the [*exception*  rather than the norm](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050114-00/?p=36693) but not what folks are saying when they say "exception-handling".)

For adjunct reading, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Exception_handling

Comment: Obvious troll is obvious. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_%28computer_science%29

Comment: @Aaronaught, While silent downvotes don't help the site, comments which explain nothing is just as non-useful. Why do you say that this is a troll answer?

Comment: @Pacerier, exceptions have nothing to do with giving up (and the paper you linked for this, has weak arguments and blanket statements). Exceptions are not "the easy way out", they are a mechanism introduced to the language, to address problems with signaling errors through error codes (they make things easier because that's what they were added to the language for).

Comment: @utnapistim, The question is comparing exception handling against the other alternatives. And yes they make things easier when there's no need for reliability yet it's the easy way out when you get to high-reliability situations. See the links I've provided, especially http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/14/352949.aspx and http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2003/10/13.html

Comment: @Pacerier: you say "easy way out" like it's a bad thing.  A good programmer writes no more than necessary, and your answer doesn't even hint at why more complexity is appropriate.

Comment: No you are absolutely wrong. Exceptions are one of the best and **most reliable** ways to do error handling. Exceptions are also almost always superior to Error Codes. There are of course drawbacks, and there are other ways to do error handling which are sometimes superior. I suggest you delete your answer for being nonsense.

Comment: Also the article by Patterson which you linked to is plain wrong. 1. Exception help **improve and simplify** control flow. not the other way around. Its far easier to have a block of code, and then error handling for it, than checking every possible return code. 2. Exception plays along very well with modern parallel programming. its very evident in C#, F#, Scala, and Erlang.

Comment: Joel is also wrong because RAII , and what he's saying isn't relevant for C# and Java for example. Also it's a blog post from 11 years ago. I really doubt he'll stand behind it today.

Comment: @DougM, The phrase "easier way" would be appropriate then. Whether that's a good or bad thing is irrelevant and will depend on each use case, as the question here is simply *"Why have many programmers moved to using exception handling for input or output?"* And the answer is because it's the economical choice. That decision has no direct relation with *theoretical correctness* nor *faulty input/output*. — Regarding the part on "more/less code", If you re-read through the links, it's evident Dijkstra's quote above is not saying that more code is a good thing, he's stating the exact opposite.

Comment: @AK_, While that's irrelevant, I really doubt he'll not stand behind it today. His post on AMA shows I'm on the right track.
Also, the links I've posted provides strong **reasoning** that exception-based code has many pitfalls. If you've skipped through all of them, you can start from Raymond Chen's **reasoned** blogpost 6 paragraphs before *"it is extraordinarily difficult to see the difference between bad exception-based code and not-bad exception-based code"*. I'll delete the ...........................................

Comment: .............................. answer only when the **reasoning** is flawed,  not just because it happens to be on the minority side (goodness **-15** votes?) of a religious flame-topic.

Comment: It's not just a minority view. You're plain wrong. This isn't the appropriate medium to explain why, but it doesn't matter. Just mind that most programming languages designed in the last 25 years use Exceptions as their main (if not only) error handling mechanism.

Comment: @Pacerier: your answer still fails to argue, at all, WHY avoiding the simple tool is worthwhile.  (And most of your links are more cranky than sensible.  I'd probably WANT a taskbar icon to show its square, even if the icon it was looking for couldn't be shown.)

Most programmers use exceptions rather than return codes because, for most PROGRAMS, exceptions are the correct choice.  If an error code rather than an exception is actually called for, you're operating at a far lower level than most code should care about.

Comment: @DougM, The explanation is so clear and straightforward that if you're asking what the reasons are, I sincerely doubt you had read them. I'll summarize the article: It's due to [1) abrupt jump 2) too many exit points](http://goo.gl/ZNLBNG). Regarding *"probably WANT a taskbar icon to show its square, even if the icon it was looking for couldn't be shown"*, That's orthogonal to the ........................................................................

Comment: ...................................................................  concept of exceptions vs ercode-based handling. You can do that with either method. Regarding *"operating at a far lower level than most code should care about"*, note that we are not comparing low level code with high level code. We're comparing exceptions vs error-handling in situations where both are available. The **flaws** of exceptions (the 2 points above) applies to **both** low level and high level code. The only difference between low level and high level is reliability: whether failure has consequences or not.

Comment: @AK_, If you are going to comment on an answer and say it's wrong, you will provide at least 1 reason why it's wrong. I see **zero**. Failing to provide any reasons renders your comment empty in content. I see many words from you but no **reasoned** points made. First thing first, programming languages aren't perfect, the.............................................................................‌​................................

Comment: ...................................point *"programming languages designed in the last 25 years use Exceptions as their main (if not only) error handling mechanism"* ipso facto provides 0 reasoning to the judgement of exceptions vs ercodes. Indeed, [Joel's article](http://goo.gl/ZNLBNG) is exactly talking about these languages C# and Java, exceptions give 1) abrupt jump 2) too many exit points.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23181/discussion-on-answer-by-pacerier-why-have-many-programmers-moved-to-using-except).

Comment: Of two highly popular languages (Objective-C and Swift), the first strongly recommends using exceptions only for programming errors and never catching them, while the other doesn't have exceptions. Both include an excellent error reporting mechanism.